# Using Euclid Elements, is it possible to bisect a line at an angle other than 90 degrees?

Tags: geometry, bisection

From Euclid's Elements, Book 1, [Proposition 10](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI10.html) shows that, the line is bisected at right angles. Is it possible to bisect a line at any angle other than 90 degree?

Comment: Well, yes: pick the mid point and draw any other line passing through it.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path: Is it possible using Euclid's Elements? I'm sorry, I'll have to rephrase the question too.

Comment: What do you mean? *Elements* most definitely accounts for the existence of non-perpendicular lines.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path : Is there a sufficient construction for this?

Comment: Defining the measure of an angle is not trivial (just as defining the real numbers). But one can construct a parallel to any given line which bisects a given segment (unless the given line is parallel to the segment).

Comment: @MarkBennet: I couldn't get the first statement. I hope the second statement states Euclid's 5th postulate indirectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can bisect a line segment with a line of almost any direction you please:

Build a triangle $ABC$ on one side; then build a congruent triangle $BAD$ on the other side with whatever method you please.  Line $CD$ will bisect $AB$.

[image]

Comment: You have to orient the triangles properly.  One possible orientation for the two triangles makes a kite, the other makes a parallelogram, and you need the latter.

Comment: gah, I intended to imply that with my letter ordering...

Comment: @DanUznanski: I hope `CD` would then be a perpendicular bisector. Is it possible to make  `CD` bisect at an angle _other_ than 90 degrees?

Comment: It can be any angle you want.  The picture illustrates one such angle.

Comment: @DanUznanski: Well, the angle shown more looks like 90. Could you show a picture with an angle 20, so I could get a better view of the answer.

Comment: @DanUznanski : Could you tell why the **CD** bisector is inclined at an angle other than 90 degrees.

Comment: every point on a perpendicular bisector of $AB$ must be equidistant from both $A$ and $B$.  This is clearly not the case here: we can choose $AB$ and $AC$ to have whatever, possibly different, lengths we please.  ...honestly, non-perpendicularity is the obvious one here.

Comment: @DanUznanski: Does _Euclid Element's_ has a similar proposition to the one stated in the first sentence. To be honest I couldn't find one.

Comment: No, for that would be unnecessary: it constructs a perpendicular bisector, thus finding the midpoint, thus allowing the later (if necessary) construction of a line through that of any other direction we please.  That's not shown though, because it doesn't get us anything new.  If you want to see this thing show up, follow the parallelogram stuff from I.34 around a while.  I don't see it off the top but it's a well known result that the diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other. (Though my construction does not, as far as I know, rely on the parallel postulate)

Comment: @DanUznanski: Does Euclid mention about a non perpendicular bisector in [Proposition 34](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI34.html)?

Comment: He does mention that the diagonal splits the parallelogram evenly.  That's about it.  I don't really understand what you're after here.  It's not like Euclid is the be-all and end-all of geometry knowledge; it's not like his path is the only one.  Why does this have to be in Euclid?  There's so much more to geometry than one millennia-old book.

Comment: @DanUznanski: Well, could you prove that $  AB  ! \perp CD  $ in the given answer?

Answer (score 2):

Let the segment be $AB$. Draw a line $L$ through A which is different from $AB$ but otherwise arbitrary. Draw a line $L'$ parallel to $L$ through $B$ using [Euclid's I.31](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI31.html). Pick a point $C \in L$ different from $A$. Construct using [Euclid's I.2](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI2.html) an equal segment $|BD|=|AC|$ with $D \in L'$, so that $C,D$ lie on opposite halfplanes cut by $AB$. Then $ACBD$ is a parallelogram, $AB$ and $CD$ are its diagonals, and therefore $AB \cap CD$ is the midpoint of $AB$.

[image]

Comment: I'm hoping that  $ AB \cap CD $ would be $AB$ or $CD$ since $AB=CD$(cause ABCD is a parallelogram). Why $ AB \cap CD $ be the midpoint of $AB$.

Comment: @justin $\,AB \cap CD\,$ is the *intersection* of the two segments. `AB=CD cause ABCD is a parallelogram` Careful with the ordering there, it is $\,A\color{red}{CB}D\,$ which is a parallelogram. $\,AB,CD\,$ are its diagonals, and $\,AB \ne CD\,$ in general. `Why AB∩CD be the midpoint of AB` Because [the diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram#Proof_that_diagonals_bisect_each_other).

Comment: Could you show a figure to illustrate your answer. I'm getting **AD** and **BC** as the diagonals of the parallelogram _ABDC_ as per the construction provided.

Comment: @justin Edited the answer to include a picture. `I'm getting AD and BC as the diagonals` Mind this part: "*so that C,D lie on* ***opposite*** *halfplanes cut by AB*".

Comment: I'm not getting why `CD` is _not_ perpendicular. Is there a sufficient proof in showing, why `CD` is not perpendicular?

Comment: @Justin You start with an arbitrary point on an arbitrary line. The chances that $CD \perp AB$ are infinitesimally small. However, if it *does* happen that $CD \perp AB$, then just choose another point $C'$ between $C$ and $A$ then construct the corresponding $D'$. Since $\angle C'AB \lt \angle CAB$ the segment $C'D'$ is assured to *not* be $\perp AB$.

Comment: Well, I couldn't get why $\angle C'AB$ seems to be lesser than $\angle CAB$. I hope both angles are the same.

Comment: @justin Sorry, meant $\,C'OA \lt COA\,$ where $O=AB \cap CD = AB \cap C'D'$.

Comment: Could you tell why is $\,C'OA \lt COA\ $?

Comment: @justin Because $\angle COA = \angle C'OA+\angle COC'$, therefore $\angle COA  \gt \angle C'OA$. Same argument is used by Euclid in step 3 of [I.20](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI20.html), for example.

Comment: That's right. So, why would $ CD  ! \perp AB$ if  $ \,C'OA \lt COA\ $?

Comment: @justin If you step back to [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835261/using-euclid-elements-is-it-possible-to-bisect-a-line-at-an-angle-other-than-90/2835277?noredirect=1#comment5870045_2835277) then you'll recall that $C'$ was only constructed if $CD \perp AB$ i.e. $\angle COA = 90^\circ$. That means that $\,\angle C'OA \lt \angle COA \iff \angle C'OA \lt 90^\circ\,$, so in particular $\,\angle C'OA \ne 90^\circ\,$. But seriously, I don't see where this line of q&a is going, so I'll just leave it at that here.

Comment: Based on the previous [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835261/using-euclid-elements-is-it-possible-to-bisect-a-line-at-an-angle-other-than-90/2835277?noredirect=1#comment5870045_2835277) , I hope that $C'$ was chosen if CD wasn't perpendicular to $AB$. Is this true?

Comment: @justin No, please read more carefully. If $CD$ is *not* perpendicular to $AB$ then you have your construction already, so there is no need for $C'$.

Answer (score 1):

A construction graphic may help to illustrate this concept. The line between circle centers is bisected by lines at $30, 45$ and $60$ degrees. These are the angles of the line between circle centers and the bisectors.

[image]

Comment: I can't understand how this figure was constructed. Could you list out the construction steps.

Comment: Establish the mid point with a regular perpendicular bisector, then: (1) construct 2 identical circles with centers at the end points with a radius of half the line length. (2) with the same radius as the circles step off two consecutive arcs around the circumference of the circles from the mid point of the line (above the line on the right circle and below the line on the left circle). From each arc on both pairs, strike two more intersecting arcs to create a point for the perpendicular lines at the endpoints. Construct the three lines at 30, 45 and 60 as shown.

Comment: I would be better if they were citations to _Euclid's Elements_ for each step. I was wondering why Euclid just came up with a **perpendicular bisector** and _not_ of any other kind like a 60 or 20 degree bisector.

Comment: That last question -- the one you seem to really want to ask -- isn't a math question. It's a psychology or history question. My guess is that Euclid came up with the perp bisector because it was really, really easy, and was pretty useful for other things he wanted to do. But that's just a guess, and can't be proven wrong or right.

Comment: @PhilH: Could you label the angles in the answer. I'm getting confused about the lines' angles.

Comment: @justin Done, see revised graphic.

Comment: @PhilH: I'm sorry but I'm still getting confused. Can you label the construction steps in the figure provided.

Answer (score 0):

Take points $A$ and $B$ on the line $\ell$. Draw a circle at $A$ with radius $r = AB$, and let the other point of intersection be called $P$. Do the same for $B$, producing $Q$. You now have four points on a line, $P-A-B-Q$.

Draw a circle at $P$ with radius $PB$, and a circle at $B$ with the same radius. These intersect at two points, and the segment $S_1$ joining these points  meets $\ell$ perpendicularly at $A$.

Do the same to produce a segment $S_2$ through $B$. Take an endpoint of $S_1$ and call it $X$; take the endpoint of $S^2$ on the other side of $\ell$, and call it $Y$. Then $XY$ is a bisector of $AB$, and the bisection is at $45$ degrees instead of $90$.

Here's a figure; I've drawn in the (green) circles used to construct $S_1$, but omitted those used to construct $S_2$, since they're very similar. 
[image]

Comment: Please show an illustration for this answer. I tried to draw a figure, but it seems that the segment $S_1$ runs on $l$ itself.

Comment: Could you tell why **XY** is the bisector of _AB_ and why the bisector is inclined at 45 degrees.

Comment: It's a bisector by symmetry: if you flip the diagram about both the vertical and horizontal axis, it remains (setwise) the same. But under this transformation, the line $\ell$ is set-wise invariant, and $A$ and $B$ swap positions; the intersection, however, does not move. As for the "45 degrees", I was mistaken about that -- it's something like $\arccos(\frac{1}{2})$ instead. Apologies.

Comment: I'm studying about Plane Geometry. However, I couldn't understand the terms like _set-wise invariant_ , _transformation_ . Do you mean that the points position in  line $l$ stays the same even after flipping vertically or horizontally? Why does **A** and **B** swap positions?

Comment: What I mean is that each point on the line $\ell$ remains a point of the line $\ell$ after the transformation, but it may move to a new position on $\ell$. If you imagine moving the line $\ell$ in the picture about an inch to the right, then $\ell$ remains setwise invariant; if you move it an inch *up*, it does not. Why do $A$ and $B$ swap positions? Well, under a vertical flip, they both remain where they are. Under the horizontal flip (switching left and right), when you make the purple circles match up (i.e., the left circle becomes the right one, and vice versa), their centers must, too.

Comment: Does this mean that the line $l$ becomes another line when it moves up or down? I have a doubt. If a line is rotated, does every point in a line retain it's original position? I hope that when a line is rotated at 180 degrees, the front point of a line becomes the back point and vice-versa. So, does the front or back point of a line remains unchanged after flipping a line vertically?

Comment: I apologize for this, but I've simply run out of time to dedicate to this answer. You'll have to work with what I have given you so far, or perhaps find something useful in someone else's answer.